# What causes an error with traceur when moving Angular2 application to new system?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an application built in Angular2 RC5. I started my app in Angular2-Beta2.0.0. I am trying to copy the application to another system to do further development. The primary system still works with no issue, but when I pull down the same code to my 2nd system I get this error every time I start my application. I cant find any mention of traceur anywhere in my project files. I dont know what this is. The app still works fine on my orig system.

```
 zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/traceur
```

Anyone know what this is and how to fix it?

Whole Error

```
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/traceur
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/traceur
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:4200/main.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/traceur
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:4200/main.js
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32)
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:523:18)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:18
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:36)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "prod-campus-081616",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "mongoService": "../Mongo/bin/mongod",
    "StartElasticSearch": "/usr/local/bin/elasticsearch",
    "StartKibana453": "/usr/local/kibana/bin/kibana",
    "node-start": "node ./bin/www",
    "angular-start": "ng serve --live-reload false",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-oauth2": "^1.3.10",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.5.0",
    "aws-sign": "^0.1.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "hbs": "~4.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "mongoosastic": "^4.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.9",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.2",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "multer-s3": "^2.3.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.24",
    "ng2-dropdown": "0.0.12",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.0.3",
    "password-hash": "^1.2.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "s3fs": "^2.4.8",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "1.3.1"
  }
}
```

**system-config.ts**

```
"use strict";

// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
  'angular2-oauth2': 'vendor/angular2-oauth2',
  'aws-sdk': 'vendor/aws-sdk',
  'aws-sign': 'vendor/aws-sign',
  'fs': 'vendor/fs',
  'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap',
  'ng2-file-upload': 'vendor/ng2-file-upload'

};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'angular2-oauth2': 'config.js',
  'aws-sdk': 'index.js',
  'aws-sign': 'index.js',
  'ng2-bootstrap': 'ng2-bootstrap.js',
  'ng2-file-upload': 'ng2-file-upload.js'

};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/header',
  'app/article',
  'app/auth',
  'app/community',
  'app/device',
  'app/error',
  'app/message',
  'app/physical-drive',
  'app/profile',
  'app/topic',
  'app/dashboard',
  'app/profile/profile-edit',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

Comment: Are you using `angular2-cookie` in your project?

Comment: no, but I do see this:  
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",

Comment: I had a similar problem today, when you click on `(...)` (three dots) after an error, you will see stacktrace which will point you to what might be problem. I found out my problem was version of `angular2-cookie`, I was using 1.1,  but I needed 1.2.3 because that is the version that supports RC6. So, you probably have a similar problem, hope this helps at least a bit.

Comment: also there are similar question on SO they talk about your router referencing rc2 rather than rc1 try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313845/angular2-rc4-to-rc5-migration-traceur-issue)

Comment: Makes sense, but this only points to more core Angular stuff - I added the whole error above to the original post

Comment: Can you please post your `package.json` and `systemjs.config.js` files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

If you run into this and have a working version of of your app on another box, copy the node_modules folder from the working system to the one having the issue, delete the contents of your dist folder, and restart your app.

**LONG ANSWER**

After searching everywhere I decided that this had to be related to packages that have been updated between the RC versions of Angular2 ***(I started this app with Beta2)*** and something that must have been changed or removed with newer versions that was there previously. Basically it seems like something was installed previously that no longer is getting installed now.

Note:

**System A** has always been working

**System B**  never worked

I copied my entire node_modules folder from **System A** to **System B**. Restarted Node and Angular2 and everything was working. So I examined this node_modules folder from **System A** in comparison to the one generated from **System B** by running an **npm install** after deleting the node_modules folder.

I noticed that **platform-browser-dynamic** has been seriously thinned out since I first installed it. (120 items on System A vs 66 items on System B)

My package.json file is identicle on both System A and B with this line:

**"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.5",**

As a first test I copied the entire folder from A to B.

Result:
Error changed, no longer complained about platform-browser-dynamic, now it said:

```
Error loading http://localhost:4200/traceur
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular/core/index.js as "@angular/core"
```

The same thing happened as I replaced Core, Compiler, Platform-browser and Common.

Once all of those folders had been replaced with the version from my other system, everything started working.

This is great, however I must say it makes me wonder how I will ever be able to deploy this app. I dont know how I could have caused this, (Welcome to suggestions), so I'm hoping this is an issue that gets resolved with the final release of Angular2.